# Anchor from another page not working in Firefox and IE (works in Chrome)

Tags: html, firefox, anchor

I've inherited a site with a problem that's driving me nuts in Firefox and IE.

There are 3 anchor tags on the site's home page. All of these anchor tags work when the visitor is on the home page, but only 2 of them work when used from other pages.

The site is http://sm.retriogroup.com

Clicking on "Menus," "Locations" or "Contact" in the header menu brings the page to the right anchor.

If you visit another page such as http://sm.retriogroup.com/gallery and then use the same links, only the "Menus" and "Contact" links work properly. The "Locations" link always goes to the bottom of the home page instead of to the anchor. (In Chrome, the page loads at the correct anchor point)

The HTML for the anchor links is the same, using an ID as the anchor name. I don't understand why this particular one isn't working, while the others do.

Frustratingly, if you use the http://sm.retriogroup.com/#location link from another page, it doesn't work. But then once you're on the home page again and click "Locations," then the anchor loads no problem!

Comment: Does it make any difference if you use `http://sm.retriogroup.com/index.php#location` instead of `http://sm.retriogroup.com/#location`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It's a Drupal site, though, so index.php shouldn't be linked to

Comment: I understand, however did you try it and did it make any difference?

Comment: Linking to index.php on a Drupal site doesn't work. The home page's full URL is sm.retriogroup.com/node and linking to sm.retriogroup.com/node#location does not make a difference

Comment: I tried copying all of the content into a regular HTML page at test.php. Still, following a link to test.php#location doesn't work, but following a link to test.php#menus does work.

Answer (score 4):

Discovered the problem by systematically erasing content on the page one-by-one.

Problem turned out to be related to a slider on the page that was being generated through javascript. Setting a height on the slider's container solved the problem.