# Named anchor from the address bar in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, scroll, anchor

I have a page with a static bar **100px** tall at the top with a menu linking to specific parts of the page:

HTML:

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="http://domain.com/#anchor1">ANCHOR 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://domain.com/#anchor2">ANCHOR 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://domain.com/#anchor3">ANCHOR 3</a></li>
</ul>

<a id="anchor1" class="anchor" name="anchor1"></a>
<h3>HEADER 1</h3>
<div>
Content 1
</div>
<a id="anchor2" class="anchor" name="anchor2"></a>
<h3>HEADER 2</h3>
<div>
Content 2
</div>
<a id="anchor3" class="anchor" name="anchor3"></a>
<h3>HEADER 3</h3>
<div>
Content 3
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.menu {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
}

a.anchor {
    display: block;
    height: 100px;
    margin-top: -100px;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Using Chrome, if I, for example, type **http://domain.com/#anchor2** in the address bar, the browser takes the anchor offset into account and scrolls to the desired point. If I do the same in Firefox, the browser seems to ignore the offset and scrolls to a wrong position. But, once I'm in the page, if I click the **ANCHOR 2** menu item the browser scrolls to the right place. It seems that Firefox is ignoring the anchor offset when loading the page for the first time.

Any ideas on making this work in Firefox?

Thanks in advance

Comment: what version of firefox are you running? I tried this and it worked for me...

Comment: I forgot about a jQuery accordion placed in the content of the page. Apparently, it's affecting the anchor offsets in both Firefox and IE. If I remove it, the anchors work as expected.

The following thread is related to my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19611089/anchor-from-another-page-not-working-in-firefox-and-ie-works-in-chrome